# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: is coming in java servlets

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Here is my servlet class

```
package com.zaggle;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class FirstServlet
 */
public class FirstServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public FirstServlet() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] data;String val=null,name;
    name=request.getParameter("excelsheet");
    System.out.println(name);
        response.setContentType("text/html");
         UploadExcel ex= new UploadExcel();
         data=ex.procedure(name);
     System.out.println(name);

    request.setAttribute("val", data);
    System.out.println(val);

    String destination="/NewFile1.jsp";
    RequestDispatcher rd=getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(destination);
    //doGet(request, response);
    rd.forward(request, response);


}

}
```

Here is my normal java class which I am using in servlet class

```
package com.zaggle;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicInternalFrameTitlePane.RestoreAction;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.record.formula.functions.Goto;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;



 public class UploadExcel {
public String[] procedure(String filename) {
    //  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
      //System.out.println("Please enter a filename with extention to upload");

    String fileName = "C:\\"+filename;//+scanner.nextLine();
    String[] dataHolder = ReadCSV(fileName);
   // printCellDataToConsole(dataHolder);
    return dataHolder;
}

public static void printCellDataToConsole(Vector dataHolder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    for(int i=0;i<dataHolder.size();i++)
    {
        Vector column=(Vector)dataHolder.elementAt(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < column.size(); j++) {
            HSSFCell myCell = (HSSFCell) column.elementAt(j);
            String stringCellValue = myCell.toString();

            System.out.print(stringCellValue + "\t");
    }
    System.out.println();

    }
}

public static String[] ReadCSV(String fileName) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     Vector cellVectorHolder = new Vector();
     String[] col = null;
     try {
         FileInputStream myInput = new FileInputStream(fileName);

         POIFSFileSystem myFileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem(myInput);

         HSSFWorkbook myWorkBook = new HSSFWorkbook(myFileSystem);

         HSSFSheet mySheet = myWorkBook.getSheetAt(0);

         Iterator rowIter = mySheet.rowIterator();

         while (rowIter.hasNext()) {
                 HSSFRow myRow = (HSSFRow) rowIter.next();
                 Iterator cellIter = myRow.cellIterator();
                 Vector column = new Vector();
                 while (cellIter.hasNext()) {
                         HSSFCell myCell = (HSSFCell) cellIter.next();
                         column.addElement(myCell);

                 }
                  col=column.toString().split(" ");
                 cellVectorHolder.addElement(column);
         }
 } catch(IOException ie)
 {
     System.err.println("Please enter a valid input");

 }
     catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
 }
 //return cellVectorHolder;
     return col;
}

}
```

When i run I am getting the error like this

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception

root cause

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/poifs/filesystem/POIFSFileSystem
com.zaggle.UploadExcel.ReadCSV(UploadExcel.java:52)
com.zaggle.UploadExcel.procedure(UploadExcel.java:24)
com.zaggle.FirstServlet.doPost(FirstServlet.java:42)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

Why am I getting this error. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Well where are all the Apache POI libraries at execution time?

Comment: Looks like your missing some Apache POI libraries in your project or at least they're missing when you deploy the web app.

Comment: @ Jon Skeet @ Luggi Mendoza I have added it in java Reference Libraries

Comment: Check that the Apache POI libraries deployed in your app contains the `org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem` class.

Comment: @Rag : You have library in class path but you need to put it in your project's `WEB-INF/lib`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you've forgotten to include the **POI library** on the `CLASSPATH` (e.g. It's not referenced by your web app). You can include this lib under `WEB-INF/lib` (in your WAR archive or in the exploded directory format) or it can sit elsewhere in your app `server/web` server `CLASSPATH`.

Answer (score 1):

you are getting the exception in this line

```
POIFSFileSystem myFileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem(myInput);
```

You are trying to use a library that is not included in your project. 
Make sure that `import org.apache.poi` library in in the `web-inf/lib` directory

Answer (score 1):

Your POI jars are not in the classpath.You can include this lib under **WEB-INF/lib.**.

Also check could be that your version of jars is different than those expected.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `apache-poi.jar` under WEB-INF/lib.

Optional : Based on the your web server or application server, put `apache-poi.jar` into `server-home`/lib(depend on server). It is not best solution.

---

**Note**

Now, you are developing web application, don't use uploaded file with specific path (eg: C:\....). If so, the program will find out the upload file on local machine `Web Server` is running. First you have to upload file as `byte[]` or `InputStream` or use other third party lib. After that, you have to change `HSSFWorkbook`.